# Closing a Frame in Java

Tags: java

I am wondering if someone can explain to me why my this will not compile?  I am trying to close a Frame in java when the user hits the [x] button.  I am not sure if you need a listener or something like that in java, but since I have been looking up this problem it seems like this is what you need.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class BallWorld
{
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    BallWorldFrame world = new BallWorldFrame();
    world.setDefaultCloseOperation(world.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    world.setVisible( true );

   }


  }
```

Comment: it does not like the line "world.setDefaultCloseOperation(world.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

Comment: What is the compile error message? "Does not like" is not a sufficient problem description. What if you change `world.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` to `BallWorldFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`?

Comment: Sorry about that, I tried your recommendation, and sadly it did nothing.  I am running in Eclipse and it says that DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE cannot be resolved to a type or is not a field.  It will not let me run it.

Comment: Hey Lewis, I have tried extending JFrame but still nothing seems to happen.

Comment: Can you supply us with the definition of `BallWorldFrame`?  As `world.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` should not stop the program from running, although the preferred method is `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is not working is because your `BallWorldFrame` class does not have the methods you are trying to call. Try this:

```
public class BallWorldFrame extends JFrame {
    ...
}
```

Notice that we are extending [`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html), thereby allowing us to utilize methods such as `setDefaultCloseOperation` and `setVisible`.

---

Now to create a button that will close the frame, you will need to use an `ActionListener`. You can try something like this (putting everything in a single class):

```
public class BallWorld extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JButton x;

    public BallWorld() {
        x = new JButton("x");
        x.addActionListener(this);
        add(x);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BallWorld();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        dispose();  // close the frame
    }
}
```

Notice how our class is now also implementing `ActionListener` and overriding `actionPerformed` to close the frame. By `x.addActionListener(this)`, we mean "when the 'x' button is clicked, perform the action defined in the `actionPerformed` method of our class, i.e. close the frame".

Comment: `BallWorld` is not the same thing as `BallWorldFrame`. Without knowing what `BallWorldFrame` actually is, it's difficult to know exactly what the problem is :P

Comment: Thank you for the help! But nonetheless, even when I extend JFrame it is saying the same error message abou setDefaultCloseOperation. Any ideas?

Comment: @EricSage Sorry, I meant have `BallWorldFrame` extend `JFrame` (see edited post).

Answer (score 0):

From what you are saying, it sounds like your `BallWorldFrame` does not extend from a `JFrame` as the default close operation is an exclusive feature of the `JFrame`

Try a simpler example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            BallWorldFrame world = new BallWorldFrame();
            // All these compile and run without issue...
            world.setDefaultCloseOperation(world.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            world.setDefaultCloseOperation(BallWorldFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            world.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            world.setVisible(true);

        }
    });

}

public static class BallWorldFrame extends JFrame {
}
```

nb The `static` decleration comes from the fact that in my example, the `BallWorldFrame` is a inner class of my main class.  If your `BallWorldFrame` exists in it's own class file, it will not need it.

Comment: @OP Of course, you should generally refrain from using something like `world.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` (since `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` is `static`).